# reference for theorem commutative ring R is semi simple iff direct product of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Can I get any reference(book or journal paper) for the theorem, Let R be a commutative ring, R is semisimple if and only if it is isomorphic to a direct product of a finite number of fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This follows immediately from [Artin-Wedderburn theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem). It states that a ring is semisimple iff it is a direct product of matrix rings over division rings (aka skew-fields); for them to be commutative, matrices have to be $1\times 1$, that is, isomorphic to scalars, and division rings have to be commutative, that is, fields.

Googling "Artin-Wedderburn theorem proof" yields a lot of results, like [this](http://www.thebookshelf.auckland.ac.nz/docs/NZJMaths/nzjmaths022/nzjmaths022-01-010.pdf), [this](https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sek/select/rw1.pdf), or [this one](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~lee/algebra/wedder.pdf).